# Deploy Rshiny app from local machine packrat project bundle to linux server

Tags: r, shiny, packrat

I have build a packrat rshiny project and bundled the project to a tar.gz file.

Now, When I am trying to move this to linux server which doesn't have Rshiny package and doesn't have privileges to install packages.

When I run the app from linux terminal with `R -e "shiny::runApp('~/shinyapp')"` I am getting error shiny package not available.

How can I initiate the packrat on server and use the shiny package available in packrat library to run the application from terminal.

Comment: Have you try to install shiny-server?

Comment: @JimChen I don't have any privileges to install anything on the server. If have to install something I can install shiny on server also and it will work fine. Then what is the point of having packrat ?